using PS customobject in foreach loop
I am writing one script to exclude all SKUs otherthan recommended in policy for that i have written script where it looks all skus and add to policy waiver list if that sku not the file i am fetching, but when i doing PScustomobject its displaying duplicate ones, Anyhelp here is much appreciated
    $exclusionsVM1 = @()
    $skus = Get-Content ".\Dseries.txt"
    
    $subs = Get-AzSubscription 
    
    
    foreach ($sub in $subs) {
        Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $sub.Id  -WarningAction Ignore | Out-Null
        $vm = Get-AzVm
        foreach ($v in $vm) {
            if (($v.hardwareprofile.VmSize -match "Standard_D") -and ($v.hardwareprofile.VmSize -notin $skus)) {
                $WaiverlistVM1 = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    VMname = $vm.Name
                    scope  = $vm.Id 
                }    | ConvertTo-Json
$exclusionsVM1 += $WaiverlistVM1            
}
        }
    }
    $exclusionsVM | Out-File ".\D_waiverlistVM.txt"
    $exclusionsVM.count
    
    foreach ($exclusionVM in $exclusionsVM) {
        try {
            New-AzPolicyExemption -Name $exclusionVM.VMname -PolicyAssignment $Policy -Scope $exclusionVM.scope -ExemptionCategory Waiver
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "Error while adding VM '$exclusionVM.VMname' to the exclusions" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }


Having problem at $exclusionsVM1 += $WaiverlistVM1 getting duplicate values

Get-AzVm is working fine, though if i am fetching from single subscription getting duplicate values in $exclusionsVM1

You’re using $v as the iteration variable in foreach( $v in $vm ) but then inside the pscustomobject constructor you’re using $vm as the property value in, e.g. VMname = $vm.Name - is that the cause of your “duplicates”?

Thanks for your finding @marsze, it solved the issue

I had so many tasks that could be coded as a foreach loop driven by an array of PScustomobject that I wrote a generic tool to processes that class of problem.  It's a very simple template engine.  It's available at http://www.github.com/dcressey/Expand-Csv

I do agree with mclayton that since you are using foreach ($v in $vms), you should use $v to store VMname and scope.
Here is the updated script to create exceptions in Azure Policy.
    # Load SKUs from Dseries.txt
    $skus = Get-Content ".\Dseries.txt"
    $Assignment = Get-AzPolicyAssignment
    
    # Initialize array for VM exclusions
    $exclusionsVM1 = @()
    
    # Get Azure subscriptions
    $subs = Get-AzSubscription
    
    foreach ($sub in $subs) {
        # Set Azure context to current subscription
        Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $sub.Id -WarningAction Ignore | Out-Null
        $vms = Get-AzVM
        
        foreach ($vs in $vms) {
            # Check if VM size matches "Standard_B2ms" or "Standard_B1s" and is not in $skus
            if ($vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize -eq "Standard_B2ms") {
                # Create custom object for waiver list
                $WaiverlistVM1 = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    VMname = $v.Name
                    Scope  = $v.Id 
                }
                
                # Add object to $exclusionsVM1 array
                $exclusionsVM1 += $WaiverlistVM1
            }
        }
    }
    
    # Output $exclusionsVM1 to JSON file
    $exclusionsVM1 | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File ".\D_waiverlistVM.txt"
    
    
    
    # Apply policy exemptions for each VM in $exclusionsVM1
    foreach ($exclusionVM in $exclusionsVM1) {
        try {
            New-AzPolicyExemption -Name $exclusionVM.VMname -PolicyAssignment $Assignment -Scope $exclusionVM.Scope -ExemptionCategory "Waiver"
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "Error while adding VM '$($exclusionVM.VMname)' to the exclusions" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }

Output:

